# Let $f(x) =\sqrt[3]{1 + \sin{x}}$ on $ℝ$. Find $T_{1,0}f$, the first order Taylor polynomial around $x_o= 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) =\sqrt[3]{1 + \sin{x}}$ on $ℝ$.  Find $T_{1,0}f$, the first order Taylor polynomial around $x_o= 0$, and give an error estimate for the approximation of $f$ by $T_{1,0}f$ on the interval$[\frac{−π}{6},\frac{π}{6}]$.

I believe I have yet to fully grasp a full understanding of taylor polynomials and as such I've been having quite some issues with this question. How does one appropriately go about solving this problem? I wish to learn so that I can solve such classes of problems without help in the future.

Comment: It's just $f(0)+xf'(0)$. The error estimate comes from the remainder term.

Comment: @David I'm failing to understand the latter part of the question give an error estimate for the approximation of $f$ by $T_{1,0}f$ on the interval$[\frac{−π}{6},\frac{π}{6}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Around zero,
$(1+x)^a
=1+ax+a(a-1)x^2/2...
$
and
$\sin(x)
=x-x^3/6+...
$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&= (1+\sin(x))^{1/3}\\
&=1+\frac13 \sin(x)+(1/3)(-2/3)\sin^2(x)/2+...\\
&=1+\frac13 \sin(x)-\sin^2(x)/9+...\\
&=1+\frac13 (x-x^3/6+...)-(x^2+...)/9+...\\
&=1+\frac13 x-\frac19 x^2+...\\
\end{array}
$

You can also do
David's suggestion
$f(x)
=f(0)+xf'(0)+...
$.

$f(0) = 1$.

$f'(x)
=\sin'(x)(\frac13 (1+\sin(x))^{-2/3})
=\cos(x)(\frac13 (1+\sin(x))^{-2/3})
$
so
$f'(0)
=\frac13
$
and
$f(x)
=1+\frac{x}{3}
+...
$.

To get further terms,
you need $f''(x)
$
which I will leave to you.

Comment: I'm failing to understand the latter part of the question give an error estimate for the approximation of $f$ by $T_{1,0}f$ on the interval$[\frac{−π}{6},\frac{π}{6}]$.